# How do I replace an array element without modifying the original array and creating copy?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a pure function that receives an array as parameter and now I want to replace an element at a given index without modifying the provided array argument.

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

```
export const muFunc = (arr) => {
    return arr.replaceElementAt(1, 'myNewValue'); // This doesnt modify arr at all
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you not copy the array and `splice`?

Comment: As the topic says - I'm trying to find out if it's possible without creating a copy of the array

Comment: arr.slice() will give you an array clone

Comment: @user2394156 I don't think so. JavaScript doesn't have Ruby's `modifier!` distinction.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why is copying the array not sufficient?

Comment: You might want to use a library such as https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/, which uses [*structural sharing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Simply copy the array. A simple way to do that is `slice`:</s>

```
export const muFunc = (arr) => {
    var newArray = arr.slice();
    newArray[1] = 'myNewValue';
    return newArray;
};
```

From a comment on the question:

> As the topic says - I'm trying to find out if it's possible without creating a copy of the array

No it's not possible — well, not *reasonably*. You have to either modify the original, or make a copy.

You *could* create proxy object that just returns a different value for the `"1"` property, but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of `Object.assign` and do something like:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const updatedArr = Object.assign([], arr, {1: 'myNewValue'});

console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(updatedArr); // [1, "myNewValue", 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use map function to achieve this

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,89];

arr.map(function (rm) {
    if (rm == 2) {
        return 3
    } else {
        return rm
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
function replace(l) {
    return l.splice("new value",1);
};
var x = replace(arr);
```